# Opera Driver Unsupported Command-Line Flag with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, driver, opera, operadriver

I am using the current opera driver with Selenium for testing of a website (so that we can support Opera as an approved browser for our website). I code in C#.

When I open Opera I get a popup at the top of the screen that states:

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0. Stability and security will suffer.

I currently setup my Opera instance with the following code:

```
string operaExeLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\74.0.3911.107\opera.exe"; 

OperaDriverService service = OperaDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Opera\", "operadriver.exe");
var operaOptions = new OperaOptions
{
   BinaryLocation = operaExeLocation,
   LeaveBrowserRunning = false
};
driver = new OperaDriver(service, operaOptions);
```

I suspect that the unsupported flag can be turned off in the operaOptions - but I haven't found any documentation on how to do that. Please help if you are familiar with setting up the driver.

[image]

Comment: By "I get a popup at the top of the screen" do you mean something in the browser window itself, or a message on the command line?

Comment: At the top of the browser window.  I added a screen snip above.

Comment: I wonder if this is due to the browser version and OperaDriver version? Looks like Opera version 74. What is the OperaDriver version?

Comment: I always keep the driver updated when opera updates - the latest driver (which is what I am using) is 88.0.4324.104.  This message has plagued me since the first time i started testing the website with Opera.(a couple of years ago).

I keep thinking that there must be a setting in Options - so i have searched for a list of available flags but have not found it.  I was hoping someone from the Opera team might be monitoring stack overflow - someone there must know.

Comment: Usually the browser and web driver versions need to be specific to reach other. U think this is your problem - the wrong web driver version for opera 74.

Comment: Hmm. According to https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases v88 is correct for v74 opera.

Comment: Greg - the driver version is definitely NOT the issue.  This problem has been there since the first time I tested Opera with selenium - many versions ago.  I always keep the driver and up to date.  I've posted about this in various boards several times over the past few years, and have never gotten an answer.  And I've noticed that I am not the only person asking about it.  
For years I have been running my tests regardless of the error - but I hate the idea of leaving an error unhandled, which is why I put this post up.  Someone who knows drivers better than me must know the answer.